# Having a class creator and a class child how can a child call creator function not having a ptr to actual creator?

Tags: c++, oop, boost

So I have a `class_instantiator` and it creates an instance of  `my_class a` inside of itself. Is  it possible for `a` to call any of class_instantiator methods, not having a pointer to class_instantiator only having its interface avaliable, is it possible with any of Boost libraries?

Pseudocode example:

```
struct my_class 
{
  void call()
  {
    try{
    call_parent_function(instansiator_function);
    }catch (exception &e)
    }
};

struct class_instantiator
{
  void instansiator_function(){ cout << "Hello!";};
  void fun()
  {
   my_class a;
   a.call();
  }
};
```

Comment: where are you deriving anything? This looks like two independent structs.

Comment: There is no concept of parent here. You are just instantiating another struct/class from within another struct/class.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you clearly explained what you're practically trying to achieve. Maybe we can then suggest a solution. As of this moment (even with your pseudo code) it all does not make a lot of sense. But that might just be me.

Comment: Having `void main()` as a class member looks like a certain other language. Are you trying to write non-C++ code in C++?

Answer (score 0):

```
[edan@edan tmp]$ g++ parent.cpp
[edan@edan tmp]$ ./a.out 
parent_method!
[edan@edan tmp]$ cat parent.cpp 
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>


class my_parent {
    protected:
        void parent_method() { std::cout << "parent_method!" << std::endl; }
};

class my_calss : public my_parent {
    public:
        void call_my_parent() { my_parent::parent_method(); }
};

int
main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<my_calss> my_ojb( new my_calss );
    my_ojb->call_my_parent();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do circular references (which is what it sounds like?) I'd say you're probably doing something wrong. Can you give us a concrete example of the sort of thing you're trying to achieve?

A child class should be able to call it's parent's methods as long as they're not private.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you are asking, but to call a member function of a class you need an an actual instance (object) of that class. However, if your function (Me::pf() in your example) does not need access to your class non-static member data, then you can declare your function as static and call it directly. I have modified your example accordingly. Also, note that you had circular references the way it was written (Hello needed to see Me's definition and vice versa) so I reorganised it slightly.

```
struct Hello 
{
    void call_static_member();
};


struct Me
{
    static void pf(){ std::cout << "Hello!";}
    void main()
    {
        Hello a;
    }
};

void Hello::call_static_member()
{
try{
    Me::pf();
}catch (exception &e){}
}
```